# Summation involving $O$-notation

Tags: asymptotics, divergent-series

> I'm reading a proof where they conclude that
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{O(\ln k)}{\epsilon^2\ln^2k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}o_k(1)  = \infty,$$
>
> for a $\epsilon > 0$. Here the subscript $k$ means that it is dependent on another function $f_k$.

I understand that a function $g \in o(1)$ means that it converges to $0$. But I guess I'm having a hard time interpreting what the summation means, i.e. does

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}o_k(1)  = \infty$$

mean the summation of functions that converge to $0$ is actually not finite? How so?

Comment: Without any further assumption we cannot conclude anything because for example, the null sequence $(0)_{k\geqslant 1}$ and the sequence $(\ln k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ are both $O(\ln k)$ but the corresponding series are rspectively convergent and divergent.

Comment: I see. If I understand correctly then it all depends on the behavior of the sequence of functions $\{f_k\}$. That, more or less, answers my question actually.

Comment: Yes it actually depends on the sequence you are looking at. Saying $f = O(g)$ just says that $g$ is larger than $f$. It is a majoration of $f$, but we cannot deduce how small $f$ is; we can only deduce how maximum $f$ may be large.